# Order by on datetime field is not working - mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get the date of last order placed and mobile# for all the customers.
This is my query.

```
 SELECT c.customer_id, c.mobile, COALESCE( MAX( o.order_datetime ) ,  '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) AS last_order_date
 FROM table_orders AS o
 RIGHT JOIN table_customers AS c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_id
 ORDER BY DATE( o.order_datetime )
```

It works fine. But not giving me data in asc order of  o.order_datetime?

What is the error in query?

Comment: shouldn't you be ordering by `last_order_date` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
 ORDER BY DATE( o.order_datetime ) DESC
```